# How do I query a field from Mongo where the value is actually a number but stored as string?

Tags: regex, mongodb, nosql, mongodb-query

The confusing part is the number in the string field can be with leading zeros but my query param will not contain that

**Object 1:**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c3f6aec29c2e3193315b485"),
"flightCode" : "000541300157840"
}
```

**Object 2:**

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c3f6aec29c2e3193315b485"),
"flightCode" : "00054130015784"
}
```

If my intent is to find flight code that matches number 54130015784, how will I write my query?

Comment: Just to be clear, you want to match object 2, right?

Comment: Thats correct. I am looking to match the 2nd Object only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need [$regex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/) operator with following regular expression:

```
var code = "541300157840";
var regex = "^0*" + code + "$"

db.col.find({ flightCode: { $regex: new RegExp(regex) } })
```

where `*` means that `0` occurs zero or more times which means that it works both for `000541300157840` and for `541300157840`

Comment: how will the regex expression change if the number actually comes from a variable.. Is this correct? /^0*var1$/ ?

Comment: @satsamsk Note that the `^` anchor is required for MongoDB to be able to use an index on this field. Without it, MongoDB won't be able to use the index and query performance would suffer.

Answer (score 1):

If you think that your data would have text flight code so the string can be identified, we can use this.

**Regex:**
`54130015784(?="\n)`

**Explanation:**

```
Positive Lookahead (?="\n)
Assert that the Regex below matches
" matches the character " literally (case sensitive)
\n matches a line-feed (newline) character (ASCII 10)
```

**Example:**
https://regex101.com/r/sF0YfH/3

Let me know if it works. If not give a clear idea what you want.